# sql server openrowset importing json files performance

Tags: json, sql-server, t-sql, bulkinsert, openrowset

I have around 400GB of json files (150MB each) that I'm importing to sqlserver with 6 files importing in parallel using ssis(machine has 6 CPUs). It's taking around 4 hours only to import the data into 6 different tables (1 per parallel process)

Are there any improvments that can be made to the below query? Or is there a better way to import this data?

```
DECLARE @json VARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @json = BulkColumn FROM OPENROWSET(BULK'D:\path', SINGLE_BLOB) JSON;
INSERT INTO table_here
SELECT columns_here
FROM OPENJSON (@json, '$.json')
WITH(columns_here)
```

Comment: To be honest given the size of the thing I'm not surprised.  What is maxdop set to?  What stats are you getting for CPU load? What about the i/o, is it to a SAN/SSD? Have you tried extracting the raw json string to SQL and performing a split via a sproc?

Comment: CPU load is between 50-90, so maybe i have room to increase there. Maxdop is default setting of 0. No, at the moment this is the only method I have tried. i/o I dont have info on that at the moment. Will tablock help here?

Comment: Are you able to set maxdop to 6?  Also tablock may help here, given the number of logs you're going to be generating without.